# Issue using print statements while debugging. Log in terminal doesn't show output

Tags: python, debugging, terminal

I cannot see a log of my print statements in the terminal. Here is a screenshot of my code with the print statements print 1 and print 2 added and my terminal that is open. What is missing? I do not see an output of 1 or 2.

[image]

Comment: code placed after the return of the function is unreachable.

Comment: Images of code are absolutely useless. See [this Meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/62576) for a list of the many reasons why you should avoid posting images. Code and errors are in text, and should be posted as such. When you created your account here, it was suggested you take the [tour] and read the [help] pages in order to familiarize yourself with this site. Please do so, especially [ask] and [mcve], before posting your next question here.

Answer (score 1):

You have your `print` statements after your `return` statements.

The `print` statements will never be reached because the function will `return` before reaching the print statements.

Try putting the `print` statements before the `return` statements

Comment: Thanks, I moved the print statement before the return statements. In the terminal is says "detected change" "reloading" But it does not give an output/log What else am I missing?

Comment: Are you querying the endpoints in your code? Browsing to `/catalog/json` should initiate the endpoint and print an output

Comment: @digi_life Did this fix your issue?

Comment: I believe I am querying the api endpoints. Though it is my first time doing so. The chrome dev console error reads: "Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery" Could it be that I am perhaps too far into my files in the terminal? I am inside of the catalog folder in the terminal. Then if the code runs /catalog/json will it not find the directory?

Comment: It looks like you may not have the `jQuery` library saved locally. Have a look at the following link for flask http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/jquery/ Maybe look to configure `jQuery` like the following `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`